# $$('a.deleteButton').invoke('observe', 'click', function(e) not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

My Code actually works quite good in chrome, but testing it in IE fails :/
e.element().hide() and e.element().insert() is not working. The Ajax.Request() is working fine in both browsers.
Any idea how to fix?

```
$$('a.deleteButton').invoke('observe', 'click', function(e) {
            var commentID = parseInt(this.readAttribute('data-commentid'));
            e.stop();
            new Ajax.Request('index.php?action=CNewsComment',
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        parameters: {entryID: commentID, cNewsAction: 'delete'},
                        onSuccess: function(transport){
                            new Effect.toggle('commentID' + commentID, 'Appear', {duration:0.5});
                            var count = parseInt($('commentsCount').innerHTML.stripTags());
                            $('commentsCount').innerHTML = count-1;
                        },
                        onLoading: function(transport){
                            e.element().hide(); //not working in IE but in Chrome

                            if ($('deleteLoading' + commentID)) {
                                $('deleteLoading' + commentID).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                e.element().up().insert ({ 
                                    'before'  : '<img id="deleteLoading' + commentID + '" src="' + RELATIVE_WCF_DIR + 'images/cNewsSpinnerS.gif" alt="" />'
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        onFailure: function(transport){ 
                            e.element().show();                         
                            $('deleteLoading' + commentID).hide();                          
                            alert("An error occurred: " + transport.status + ' - ' + transport.statusText);
                        }
            });
    });
```

**UPDATE:
If I put the code which is not working in IE outside the AJAx-Request, it is working:**

```
$$('a.deleteButton').invoke('observe', 'click', function(event) {
            event.stop();
            // IE PART START
            event.element().hide();
            if ($('deleteLoading' + commentID)) {
                $('deleteLoading' + commentID).show();
            }
            else {
                event.element().up().insert ({ 
                'before'  : '<img id="deleteLoading' + commentID + '" src="' + RELATIVE_WCF_DIR + 'images/cNewsSpinnerS.gif" alt="" />'
                });
            }
            // IE PART END
            new Ajax.Request('index.php?action=CNewsComment',
                    {
                        method: 'POST',
                        parameters: {entryID: commentID, cNewsAction: 'delete'},
                        onLoading: function(transport){
                        }
```

But inside the onLoading-function it isnt, why?!

Comment: Can you either strip this down to the bare minimum of code that's not working in IE but does work in other browsers? Or create a working fiddle?

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: protoaculous.1.8.2.min.js which is prototype 1.6.0.3

Comment: tried it with the newest prototype version, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$$('a.deleteButton').invoke('observe', 'click', function(e) {
        var commentID = parseInt(this.readAttribute('data-commentid'));
        e.stop();
        new Ajax.Request('index.php?action=CNewsComment',
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    parameters: {entryID: commentID, cNewsAction: 'delete'},
                    onSuccess: function(transport){
                        new Effect.toggle('commentID' + commentID, 'Appear', {duration:0.5});
                        var count = parseInt($('commentsCount').innerHTML.stripTags());
                        $('commentsCount').innerHTML = count-1;
                    },
                    onLoading: (function(transport, e){
                        e.element().hide(); //not working in IE but in Chrome

                        if ($('deleteLoading' + commentID)) {
                            $('deleteLoading' + commentID).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            e.element().up().insert ({ 
                                'before'  : '<img id="deleteLoading' + commentID + '" src="' + RELATIVE_WCF_DIR + 'images/cNewsSpinnerS.gif" alt="" />'
                            });
                        }
                    }).bindAsEventListener(this),
                    onFailure: function(transport){ 
                        e.element().show();                         
                        $('deleteLoading' + commentID).hide();                          
                        alert("An error occurred: " + transport.status + ' - ' + transport.statusText);
                    }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $$('a.deleteButton').invoke('observe', 'click', function(e) {
        var element = e.element();
        var commentID = parseInt(this.readAttribute('data-commentid'));
        e.stop();
        new Ajax.Request('index.php?action=CNewsComment', {
            method: 'POST',
            parameters: {entryID: commentID, cNewsAction: 'delete'},
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                new Effect.toggle('commentID' + commentID, 'Appear', {duration:0.5});
                var count = parseInt($('commentsCount').innerHTML.stripTags());
                $('commentsCount').innerHTML = count-1;
            },
            onLoading: function(transport) {
                element.hide(); // not working in IE but in Chrome

                var delId = 'deleteLoading' + commentID;
                if ($(delId)) {
                    $(delId).show();
                } else {
                    element.up().insert({ 
                        'before': '<img id="' + delId + '" src="' + RELATIVE_WCF_DIR + 'images/cNewsSpinnerS.gif" alt="" />'
                    });
                }
            },
            onFailure: function(transport) { 
                element.show();                         
                $('deleteLoading' + commentID).hide();                          
                alert("An error occurred: " + transport.status + ' - ' + transport.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

If this code doesn't work then try to replace `onLoading` with this variant:

```
            onLoading: function(element, transport) {
                element.hide(); // not working in IE but in Chrome

                var delId = 'deleteLoading' + commentID;
                if ($(delId)) {
                    $(delId).show();
                } else {
                    element.up().insert({ 
                        'before': '<img id="' + delId + '" src="' + RELATIVE_WCF_DIR + 'images/cNewsSpinnerS.gif" alt="" />'
                    });
                }
            }.curry(element),
```

P.S. Which IE version you use? Older IEs had single global event object `window.event`, and at the time of asynchronous callback your `e` even in closure may point not to your original click event, but to some another event fired right before `onLoading` was invoked.

Answer (score -1):

I just know a little about prototype. but how about you debug to check whether the 'e' is the element that you want to use. Sometimes I got this kind of issue.

Comment: Just checked if the IE is jumping into the onLoading status - and it does. How would you debug it? IE does not give any javascript errors..

Comment: I try to give you my hand.  I feel sorry that it's not helpful. But you are so mean. If you don't need help, why youu ask for help.

Comment: I didn't downvote either but this would have been more appropriate as a comment, not an answer.